# C++ , read line by line and search a keyword that links to a line in a file

Tags: c++, parsing

I've been working for days now on a machine simulator that reads instructions from a file. Just started working with C++ and im studying on vectors and parsing.

A sample file looks like this :

```
label0: left
right
if <1> goto label1
write 0
goto label2
label1: right
write 1
label2: halt
```

my code for the tape looks like this :

```
int main() {
    int total_lines=0;
    int RWH=0;
    // Create a vector of strings
        std::vector<string> Instruction;
        // Create a string variable to hold each line read from the file.
        string InstLine;
        // Read through file and push onto our vector
    vector<char> TapeVector; //declare tape       
    char temp;
    cin >> noskipws;
    cout << "Enter the input (end with ~):"; //initialize tape
    while (cin >> temp && temp != '~') {
    TapeVector.push_back(temp);                
    }
    cout << "INPUT:";
        for (int i=0;i<TapeVector.size();++i) 
        {  
        cout << TapeVector[i];             
        }
        cout << endl;

    // Open our file
    ifstream InFile("input.txt",ifstream::in);
    // If we can read/write great
    if (InFile.good())  
    {
        {
        while(std::getline(InFile, InstLine))
             Instruction.push_back(InstLine);
             ++total_lines;
        }


    }
    else
        cout << "Error reading file";

and here is for the parsing which I'm having problems:

while (std::getline(infile, line))
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    string a, b, c, d;

    if (iss >> a >> b >> c >> d) //if 4 parameters
       {
            if (a=="if" && b==VectorTape[RWH])
            { 
                counter=0; // counter will reset if b 

            }
            ;
       }
    else if (iss >> a >> b >> ) //if 2 parameters
       {
            if (a=="goto" //unfinished
       }
    else if (iss >> a >> b) //if 2 parameters
       {
            if (a=="goto" //unfinished
       }
    else if (iss >> a) //if 1 parameter
       {

       } 



enter code here
```

on line 3 if label1 is detected, how do I jump and read the line with the label label1?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "label.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int RWH=0;
    std::vector<string> Instruction;    
    int total_lines=0;  

    vector<char> TapeVector; //declare tape       
    char temp;
    cin >> noskipws;
    cout << "Enter the input (end with ~):"; //initialize tape

    while (cin >> temp && temp != '~') 
          {
               TapeVector.push_back(temp);                
          }
    cout << "INPUT:";

    for (int j=0;j<TapeVector.size();++j) 
          {  
               cout << TapeVector[j];             
          }
    cout << endl;

    // Open our file
    ifstream InFile("input.txt",ifstream::in);
    // If we can read/write great
    if (InFile.good())  
    {
        {        
        string InstLine;
        // Read through file and push onto our vector
        while(std::getline(InFile, InstLine))
             Instruction.push_back(InstLine);
             ++total_lines;
        }        
    }
    else
        cout << "Error reading file";

    vector<string> labels;    
    labels = lookupLabels(Instruction);
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < Instruction.size()) 
    {
          istringstream iss(Instruction[i]);
          // ...
          string a,b,c,d;

          iss >> a >> b >> c >> d;
          if (a == "if")
          {
                if (b == TapeVector[RWH])
                {
                    i = labels[d];
                    continue;
                }
                else
                ;
          }
          else if (a == "goto") 
          {
               i=labels[b];
               continue;
          }
          else if (a == "write")
          {
               b = TapeVector[RWH];
          }
          else if (a == "right")
          {
               ++RWH;
          }
          else if (a == "left")
          {
               --RWH;
          }
          else if (a == "halt")
          {
               goto end;
          }
          else
          {
              continue;
          }
          ++i;
    } //end while
    end:
    for (int k=0;k<TapeVector.size();++k) 
          {  
               cout << TapeVector[k];             
          }
    cout << endl;
    InFile.close();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;


}
```

this is what i've done so far.. but there are plenty of errors i dont seem to understand.

```
51 C:\Users\JHONIN\Documents\THISIS\readtest 2.cpp no match for 'operator=' in 'labels = lookupLabels(const std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)()' 
55 C:\Users\JHONIN\Documents\THISIS\readtest 2.cpp variable `std::istringstream iss' has initializer but incomplete type
```

Comment: `istream::operator>>` is a terrible tool for reading line by line. use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: You will need to parse your file several times, because the goto statements make it non-linear to read.

Comment: I tried to use std::getline() initially but I want to read single words on each line because they act as machine commands. Im still searching for a better way than what I posted though. Thanks

Comment: @georgesl any idea on how to do the logic behind this? Anything will help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just jump forward in input file to unknown location.
You need to read entire program, store it in memory in a datastructure, at least annotated with labels, then jump within that structure, e.g.:

```
typedef map<string, size_t> Labels; // map label -> position in Instructions vector;

Labels lookupLabels(const vector<string>& instr) {
    Labels ret;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < instr.size(); ++i) {
        const string& s = instr[i];
        size_t colonpos = s.find(':');
        if (colonpos != string::npos)
            ret[s.substr(0, colonpos)] = i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

now you can modify you "parsing with problems" in the same way - i.e. loop over lines in instructions vector, not in file. Once you hit a `goto` just pick another line number in `labels` and proceed with it, roughly like this

```
labels = lookupLabels(Instruction)
size_t i = 0;
while (i < Instruction.size()) {
    istringstream iss(Instruction[i]);
    // ...
    iss >> a;
    if (a == "goto") {
        string label;
        iss >> label;
        i = labels[label];
        continue;
    }
++i;
}
```

Comment: if (a == "goto") {
i = labels[a] - 1; // I dont get why a is the index of labels. When a line is read and goto is found, the next word of that line is the label which it will search and jump towards that line with word and ":". So should it be if (a == "goto") {
//insert function to reset reading of lines to search for b
instr.find(b)

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake -- it should be not labels[a] but labels[b] to get jump line index. I fixed the code, moved read of label info "goto" branch and also changed for with while so i is incremented explicitly

Comment: So to rephrase: first make an index of the form <label name> -> <line number> in one cycle over all lines and then use it in another cycle

Comment: iss >> a >> b; //added b to check what label.
    if (a == "goto") {
        string label;
        b = label;
        iss >> label;
        i = labels[label];
        continue;
    } //what happens here? does it find and jump to label=b? will i(counter) still be incremented  while searching for label=b? It needs to reset the counter (i) of reading the lines then increment it per line while ignoring them until it reaches to the label so it can proceed reading the next line. or just make a separate counter to avoid confusion?please correct me if im wrong